# Onesignal is sticking and not removing in gradle

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, dart

I was installing Onesignal in my app but suddenly i got this error.
I Removed everything connected in onesignal and still getting this error..

**VS CODE ERROR while debugging :**

```
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 incompatible Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :app
WARNING: API 'variant.getJavaCompile()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getJavaCompileProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variant.getJavaCompile(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace.

> Configure project :firebase_admob

Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':firebase_admob'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':firebase_admob:classpath'.
   > Could not find any matches for gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.4, 0.99.99] as no versions of gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin are available.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/gradle/plugin/com/onesignal/onesignal-gradle-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/gradle/plugin/com/onesignal/onesignal-gradle-plugin/
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/gradle/plugin/com/onesignal/onesignal-gradle-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/gradle/plugin/com/onesignal/onesignal-gradle-plugin/
     Required by:
         project :firebase_admob

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s
  Command: C:\Users\Anonymous\Desktop\newwwapp\android\gradlew.bat app:properties
```

**Android Studio error :**

```
Could not find any matches for gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.4, 0.99.99] as no versions of gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin are available.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/gradle/plugin/com/onesignal/onesignal-gradle-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/gradle/plugin/com/onesignal/onesignal-gradle-plugin/
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/gradle/plugin/com/onesignal/onesignal-gradle-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/gradle/plugin/com/onesignal/onesignal-gradle-plugin/
Required by:
    project :firebase_admob
```

Adnroid/Build.gradle icludes :

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and this is the app/build.gradle :

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.lottothesmartapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

I remember that i did not change any inner codes in gradle i just added some codes implements in the build.gradle only and debugged. 
then removed the added codes to remove the error shown above and sticked without any changes. 
Any solution please ?

Comment: try clean build the app and then do an `Invalidate cache/restart`

Comment: I cleaned and rebuild, Invalidate cache/restart and did not work.

Comment: If you are using android studio it's in the File menu.

Comment: yes, just did it and did not work..

Answer (score 0):

Do you load the onesignal library from pubspec.yaml? Maybe it's in the pubspec.lock.

Comment: Yaml is cleared and .lock too
I deleted the build folder..
I removed every thing and cleaned..